# nginx regex rewrite rule for images

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I have the following URLs:

- www.example.com/data/images/13122013-002_IM1621.jpg
- www.example.com/data/images/13122013-002_IM1622.jpg
- www.example.com/data/images/13122013-002_IM1622.jpg

On the file system images are named:

- 1621.jpg
- 1622.jpg
- 1623.jpg

What is the correct rewrite rule? I've tried:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/.*_IM(.*)$ /data/images/$1;
}
```

But I keep receiving a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Change location to `location ~ \.jpg$` (or to more specific path, but regex)
and check.

Note that regex locations will be used in the order in config, not by "best match"

"/" might not work because it matches any request it will be used as a last resort (probably - we don't see your config)